# Python Dictionary with pyodbc

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc

I'm trying to make a query taking from one server some data, but now I'm want to make multiple queries and multiple connections, this is the problem:

I want to make a for, passing with all my connections and save my "IN" conditions for each one:

```
if len(su_dict['dst_srv']) > 1:
    su_dict['skill'].clear()
    su_dict['vdn'].clear()
    i = 0
    for x in range(len(su_dict['dst_srv'])):
        skill_varios = {}
        sql = ("SELECT skill FROM info_skill_vdn_campana WHERE activo = 1 AND pbx = 'V2' AND dst_srv = '"+str(list(su_dict['dst_srv'])[i])+"';")
        skill = crsr_kala.execute(sql).fetchall()
        skill_varios[str(list(su_dict['dst_srv'])[i])] = ', '.join([x[0] for x in skill])
        i += 1
    print skill_varios
```

The problem here is that when I printed my result on the screen it only saved the last IN condition, but I dunno why...

This is the result of the dictionary:

```
{'172.59.80.101': '2474, 2475, 2477, 2476'}
```

But it must be this because I have 2 servers:

```
{'172.59.80.01': '2474, 2475, 2477, 2476' '172.80.52.31': '54, 60, 80, 787'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the dictionary to be blank inside the `for` loop, so it will only contain the last record set. Try this:

```
if len(su_dict['dst_srv']) > 1:
    su_dict['skill'].clear()
    su_dict['vdn'].clear()
    i = 0
    skill_varios = {}

    for x in range(len(su_dict['dst_srv'])):
        sql = ("SELECT skill FROM info_skill_vdn_campana WHERE activo = 1 AND pbx = 'V2' AND dst_srv = '"+str(list(su_dict['dst_srv'])[i])+"';")
        skill = crsr_kala.execute(sql).fetchall()
        skill_varios[str(list(su_dict['dst_srv'])[i])] = ', '.join([x[0] for x in skill])
        i += 1

    print(skill_varios)
```

Good luck!

Comment: This code contains a potential SQL injection vulnerability.